# Pen tool changing colors on gradient when saving

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I am somewhat new to PS and have upgraded to CS6, and I am having issues when I save a file.

The shapes I have created (with the pen tool) and added specific gradients to, change colors. When I reopen the fill all the shapes have changed to the two colors that are currently on the foreground and background. Hence all the gradients are just those two colors and all the work matching and adding colors has been lost.

What am I doing or not doing that will prevent this from happening?

Comment: I had this bug once, every time I've changed my selected color, fill inside shapes gone bad and got reseted to some particular setting (not to picked one).
I couldn't figure out how to reproduce this bug.